# Ext.ux.TDGi.iconMgr for ExtJS 4

Tags: css, plugins, extjs, icons, extjs4

Ext.ux.TDGi.iconMgr for ExtJS 4

Do anybody ported Ext.ux.TDGi.iconMgr plugin to extJS 4?
 (http://tdg-i.com/44/extuxtdgiiconmgr...-icons-and-css)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't see it but looking at the source, it wouldn't be hard to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library from GitHub:

https://github.com/lopezdonaque/CommonJS-Framework/blob/master/src/ui/IconMgr.js